# Efficient environment for viewing logs

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, logging

Currently I am using `tail -f` for viewing logs.

Is there any more efficient/readable/better way of viewing logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! `perl` stand for *Practical Extraction and Research Language*.

Instead of using `shell` syntaxes, like:

```
tail -f file | grep --line-buffered someting
```

or

```
tail -f file | sed -une '/someting/{s/^.*:/doing some formatting/;p}'
```

(Nota: `--line-buffered` in `grep`, like `-u` in `sed` are usefull to prevent *buffering by fixed size blocks*)

For viewing/browsing logs, `perl` is *the* language.

Depending on *what you're awaiting for...* you may have to build a little script for matching exactly your need.

You may found some useable samples in perlfaq, like in `perldoc perlfaq5` (or `man perlfaq5` if you've not installed `perldoc`), there is a question: ***How do I do a "tail -f" in perl?*** where I've taked this:

> First try
>
> ```
> seek(GWFILE, 0, 1);
> ```
>
> The statement `seek(GWFILE, 0, 1)` doesn't change the current position,
>   but it does clear the end-of-file condition on the handle, so that the
>   next `<GWFILE>` makes Perl try again to read something.
>
> If that doesn't work (it relies on features of your stdio
>   implementation), then you need something more like this:
>
> ```
> for (;;) {
>     for ($curpos = tell(GWFILE); <GWFILE>; $curpos = tell(GWFILE)) {
>       # search for some stuff and put it into files
>     }
>     # sleep for a while
>     seek(GWFILE, $curpos, 0);  # seek to where we had been
>   }
> ```

I've already used this many times for triggering special cases.

#### DEMO

For sample, there is a `quick and dirty` **real-time log counter** try it! (need read access to `/var/log/syslog` ;-) :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
my %counter;

open FH, "</var/log/syslog" or die;
my $curpos = ( stat FH )[7];
seek( FH, $curpos, 0 );

for ( ; ; ) {
    for ( $curpos = tell(FH) ; <FH> ; $curpos = tell(FH) ) {
        $counter{$3}++ if /^(\S+\s+){4}(\S+\/|)([^\/\[:]*)[\[:]/;
    }
    syswrite STDOUT, sprintf "\r%s\e[K",
      join( ", ", map { sprintf "%s:%s", $_, $counter{$_} } keys %counter );
    select undef,undef,undef,1;
    seek( FH, $curpos, 0 );
}
```

Would produce one line, self-refreashing every seconds, containing all seen *daemon*'s name and a counter for each of them:

```
smtp:6, pop3d-ssl:13, local:6, imapd:8, smtpd:30, CRON:5, pickup:1, named:1
```

Answer (score 1):

As F. Hauri suggests, you could use perl to format the output.

For my usage, I created an alias for tail in my `~/.bashrc` to read my Glassfish's logs. It is very simple (one line) and colorizes my output to underline error/warning lines:

```
tail-color() {
    tail $* | perl -p -e 's/(.*WARN.*)/\033[31;43;1m$1\033[0m\007/g;' -e 's/(.*ERROR.*)/\033[33;41;1m$1\033[0m\007/g;' -e 's/(.*SEVERE.*)/\033[33;41;1m$1\033[0m\007/g'
}
```

1. `-p` : wraps the script inside a loop and outputs the processed line
2. `-e 's/(.*WARN.*)/\033[31;43;1m$1\033[0m\007/g;'` colorizes every line containing "WARN"

   - `\033[` begins escape sequence (enables formatting)
   - `31` means red foreground
   - `43` means yellow background
   - `1` enables bold characters
   - `m` closes escape sequence
   - `$1` includes the input line
   - `\033[0m` is a second sequence to put default formatting back to standard, after the line has been outputs
   - `\007` beeps
3. `-e 's/(.*ERROR.*)/\033[33;41;1m$1\033[0m\007/g;'` colorizes every line containing "ERROR" ; the only differences concern colors:

   - `31` means yellow foreground
   - `43` means red background

In my case, I toggled visual bell on, so my screen blinks on error (and my speaker doesn't beep) and error/warning lines can be detected very quickly.

You can get more information about:

- [`perl -p`](http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/PERL/node164.html)  command
- [Text formatting](http://linux.about.com/library/bl/open/newbie/blnewbie3.4.3.htm) in shell

Again, as F. Hauri explains in his answer, you can do many things thanks to perl, so you could "develop" your own log reader depending on your needs.

Comment: For more portability, try to use `tput` instead of *ansi codes*: `my $red=\`tput setf 4\`` or `$bold=\`tput bold\`` or via `Term::Cap(3perl)`. (see `man terminfo`)